# In emacs, is there a way to Hex edit/view a buffer without losing the undo info?

Tags: emacs, binary, hex

When I use *hexl-mode* in emacs, it discards the buffer's undo info.
Is there another way to hex-edit the buffer and yet retain the undo info?

If there is no alternative hex-editor, is there a hex-viewer which can view the buffer?  I have tried *[hexview-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HexviewMode)*, but it doesn't view the actual buffer; it views the buffer's *file (from disk)*, so I don't see the current edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function which copies the contents of the current buffer into a new buffer and runs hexl-mode on that:

```
(defun hexify-buffer-copy()
    "Edit current buffer in hexl mode by copying it"
    (let ((orig-buffer (current-buffer)))
         (switch-to-buffer (create-file-buffer
             (buffer-file-name orig-buffer)))
         (insert-buffer orig-buffer)
         (setq buffer-undo-list nil)
         (hexl-mode)))
```

Run with `M-: (hexify-buffer-copy)`

Answer (score 0):

There's nhexl-mode in ELPA, which uses overlays instead of rewriting the buffer, and thus keeps undo info.